# How would I call a method that declares an ArrayList and references a variable from another method?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, process, destroy

So I want to do `destroyProcesses(processes);` when I click my `stopButton` which is a `JButton`. How would I get this to work in my code?

Here is my code:

```
        private void Processes() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // New Thread "processesThread" will start here.
            final Object mon = threadBlock;
            Thread processesThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (mon) {
                        try {
                            try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();
            // "runnableTogether" will be the number that the user inputs in the GUI.
            switch (runnableTogether) {
                case 4:
                    processes.add(rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/SoundRecorder.exe"));
                case 3:
                    processes.add(rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/taskmgr.exe"));
                case 2:
                    processes.add(rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe"));
                case 1:
                    processes.add(rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe"));
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    destroyProcesses(processes);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
            }
            mon.wait();
                } catch (IOException ex) { 
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    });
            processesThread.start();
            // New Thread "processesThread" will end here.
        }
        private void destroyProcesses(List<Process> processes) {
            if (processes == null) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                for (Process thisProcess : processes) {
                    thisProcess.destroy();
                }
                processes.clear();
            }
        }
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == stopButton) {
            try {
                // Destroy processes here.
                System.exit(0);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work.

Comment: Post the specific code and explain your problem in a better way .

Comment: And please fix the formatting of your code - we really don't need to see a blank line between every real line of code for the second half...

Comment: I have never worked with arrays or lists before, so I am learning right now. I tried putting the `destroyProcesses(processes);` in my `actionPerformed()` method in the section that listens to my `stopButton`. No matter what I tried, it said, "cannot find variable in class such-and-such".

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, that is just my OCD. I like to have everything neat and organized.

Comment: @user2506658: That's *not* neat and organized. That many blank lines? And bad indentation? (Look at the indentation within actionPerformed, for example.) If it were neat and organized, I wouldn't have complained...

Comment: @user2506658 Sorry, but there are not many standards by which this is 'neat and organized', no matter the level of OCD. You are not even consistent in this, sometimes you jump in, sometimes you don't. Could you please focus on the core of your problem, and not post 100+ LOC. Btw, the 'processes' variable is a local variable. This means it's not available anywhere but the method it's defined in. Instead, make it an instance variable or separate your concerns a bit better (ie, not mixing logic with UI code)

Comment: @JonSkeet To me that is... The blank lines help to seperate different sections of the code. For example, for when I am setting up the front-end of the GUI, I had each section grouped together. The `setSize();`'s were together, the `setLocation();`'s were together, etc.

Comment: @user2506658: There were blank lines within an `if` statement which just contained a return statement. There's really no reason for that. Anyway, it's good to see that you've now edited it to far less code.

Comment: @ErikPragt Is this where the variable is being defined as a local variable: `List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();`?
Sorry I am still learning...

Comment: @JonSkeet I know, and I am sorry. I just like to seperate the braces from the rest of the code. I don't like certain parts of the code touching. It's weird, I know. But that's OCD in a nutshell :l

Comment: @user2506658: It would be wise to try to get rid of that habit if at all possible. Even if you're currently working alone, sooner or later you're going to have to work with someone else, and they're really not going to want that level of whitespace...

Comment: @user2506658 No problem, and yes, that's the place. Put defining the variable at the level of the class, instead of the method. That way the list of processes is available in the whole class, instead of only the method. Make sure that the process list is initialized before you access it, else you'll get NullPointerExceptions (NPE's). Regarding your code formatting: press reformat in IntelliJ or Eclipse. That's considered sensible formatting by most people, and I'd advise to stick to that convention, not invent your own.

Comment: @ErikPragt Oh, so you mean a global variable?

Comment: @ErikPragt Thank you so much! That worked like a charm! And thanks to everyone else as well! I will work on my bad spacing habits!!

Comment: @user2506658 Almost. A global variable is a static variable, and there's only 1 per class. A instance variable is defined at the class level, but without the static, meaning there's one per instance of the class (in other words, one per object)

Comment: @user2506658 No problem. I've put the answer here below, so that people don't have to read this whole list of comments to get to the essence of this thread :)

Comment: @ErikPragt Actually, I just moved `List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();` to the class level and made it `private static List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();` That's what made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the processes as a instance variable, like the following:

```
public class MyClass {
    private List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();

    public MyClass() {
        initProcesses();
    }

    private void initProcesses() {
        // init the processes here
    }

    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        // now here you can use the processes
    }        
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This isn't the answer that worked for me, it was the suggestion you made in the comments above. But I will choose this as the answer because you did help me find the answer.
NOTE: Look in the comments under the question for the answer!

Comment: @user2506658 Thanks for accepting the answer, but using the static is not a good approach. Remove the static, it should not be a class variable (shared by all classes), but an instance variable (available only in the current instance of the class). I've changed my answer slightly.

Comment: @user2506658 can you post the actual answer? as it may be confusing for those who will read this question and will think that the answer was the one you chose

Comment: @ErikPragt Ok, I removed the `static` and it works still!

Comment: @ErikPragt Ok, added the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Move the local variable `List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();` to the class level and add a modifier before declaring the variable, in this case, it was `private`.

```
public class yourProgram {

private List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>(); // This was moved from directly after setting up the Runtime. 

    private void Processes() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // New Thread "processesThread" will start here.
        final Object mon = threadBlock;
        Thread processesThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (mon) {
                    try {
                        try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        // "runnableTogether" will be the number that the user inputs in the GUI.
        switch (runnableTogether) {
            case 4:
                processes.add(rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/SoundRecorder.exe"));
            case 3:
                processes.add(rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/taskmgr.exe"));
            case 2:
                processes.add(rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe"));
            case 1:
                processes.add(rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe"));
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                destroyProcesses(processes);
                break;
            default:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
        }
        mon.wait();
            } catch (IOException ex) { 
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
});
        processesThread.start();
        // New Thread "processesThread" will end here.
    }
    private void destroyProcesses(List<Process> processes) {
        if (processes == null) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            for (Process thisProcess : processes) {
                thisProcess.destroy();
            }
            processes.clear();
        }
    }
public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == stopButton) {
        try {
            // Destroy processes here.
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```